# Calling a component's function from transclusion

Tags: angularjs

I have a an angular (js) component which renders selectable options.

```
<my-select options="mainVm.options"></my-select>
```

Here is the component template:

```
<a href ng-repeat="option in mySelectVm.options" ng-click="mySelectVm.select(option)">{{option.label }}</a>
```

There are some cases where I need to use a transclusion so that I have more control of how the options are displayed. Ideally, this is what it would like:

```
<my-select>
    <options-template>
        <a href ng-repeat="option in mainVm.options" ng-click="mySelectVm.select(option)">{{ option.label }} ({{ option.altLabel }})</a>
    </options-template>
</my-select>
```

However, I'm not sure if it's possible to actually access the `select()` function that is inside the mySelect component. `mySelectVm` would have no context at this point. Is there any other way to re-use the `select()` function outside of the component?

Plunker example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/2N1oGLGQFPZiY6BnIqMl?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going with this solution..

```
bindings: {
  ...
  vmForTemplate: '=?',
},
controller: function Controller() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.$postLink = function() {
    vm.vmForTemplate = vm;
  };

  vm.select = function(option) {
    vm.selectedOption = option;
  };
},
```

Component template:

```
<my-select vm-for-template="mySelectVm">
  <options-template>
    <a href ng-repeat="option in mainVm.options" ng-click="mySelectVm.select(option)">{{ option.label }} ({{ option.altLabel }})</a>
  </options-template>
</my-select>
```

Plunker example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/ckLAZXH7XLrahmyP1T75?p=preview

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. For others here, if using a directive over component use scope, not bindings.